# Sorting array value in descending order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I sort the values in descending order? I've tried arsort(); but it doesn't work in my case:

```
$text1 = 'Android SDK, application, familiar with MVP architecture, android studio, angular, angular js';

$skill = array("android sdk"=>"3", "application"=>"1", "angular"=>"2", "android studio"=>"3", "angular js"=>"3");

foreach ($skill as $skills => $weight)            {

if (preg_match_all("~\b$skills\b~i", $text1, $matchWords)) {  

$matchWords = $matchWords[0];

$matchWords = array_unique($matchWords);

}  

$text2 = 'Native Android development';

// Filter $words, keep only the items that are not present in $text2
$missing = array_filter(
    $matchWords,
    function($w) use ($text2) {
        // return TRUE when $w is not in $text
        return preg_match('/\b'.preg_quote($w, '/').'\b/i', $text2) == 0;
});


$weight = array($weight);
$dev = array_combine($missing, $weight);
arsort($dev);

foreach($dev as $x => $x_value) 
     echo "Key: " . $x . " Value: " . $x_value;
     echo "<br>";

}
```

Output:

Key: Android SDK Value: 3
Key: application Value: 1
Key: angular Value: 2
Key: android studio Value: 3
Key: angular js Value: 3

But I'd like to get this result:

Key: Android SDK Value: 3
Key: android studio Value: 3
Key: angular js Value: 3
Key: angular Value: 2
Key: application Value: 1

EDIT:

I haven't found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541082/how-to-arsort-the-following-array) as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your array is not being sorted correctly is because you are attempting to sort a single element array. If you put debugging prints in your code you will see that `$dev` only ever has one element when you call `arsort`. You need to assemble `$dev` in the loop, then sort it afterwards. Try something like this:

```
$text1 = 'Android SDK, application, familiar with MVP architecture, android studio, angular, angular js';
$text2 = 'Native Android development';
$skill = array("android sdk"=>"3", "application"=>"1", "angular"=>"2", "android studio"=>"3", "angular js"=>"3");

foreach ($skill as $skills => $weight) {
    if (preg_match_all("~\b$skills\b~i", $text1, $matchWords)) {  
        $matchWords = $matchWords[0];
        $matchWords = array_unique($matchWords);
    }  
    // Filter $words, keep only the items that are not present in $text2
    $missing = array_filter(
        $matchWords,
        function($w) use ($text2) {
            // return TRUE when $w is not in $text
            return preg_match('/\b'.preg_quote($w, '/').'\b/i', $text2) == 0;
    });

    if (count($missing)) $dev[$missing[0]] = $weight;
}
arsort($dev);

foreach($dev as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Key: " . $x . " Value: " . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
Key: Android SDK Value: 3
Key: android studio Value: 3
Key: angular js Value: 3
Key: angular Value: 2
Key: application Value: 1
```

Your loop code could be simplified greatly but that's another question...

Comment: Thanks Nick, this works for me. Although I'm confused about this: `if (count($missing)) $dev[$missing[0]] = $weight;` I also don't really understand why the array from ` $dev = array_combine($missing, $weight); ` didn't work. Will study this. Any hints also to simplify the loop would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Seb, I think if you put debugging prints into the loop you'll find a lot of code doesn't do very much e.g. `$matchWords` will only ever contain one entry which is the current value of `$skills` so you can probably get rid of that code (and just `continue` the loop if the `preg_match` fails), and also since `$matchWords` only has one value you can just do a `preg_match` instead of an `array_filter` with a function that calls `preg_match`. Hope this helps.

Comment: The `if (count($missing)) $dev[$missing[0]] = $weight;` statement is just checking that there is a value in `$missing` before attempting to add the value to the `$dev` array. Your `array_combine` statement works but is unnecessary since `$missing` will only ever have one value (see my previous comment for why that is).

Answer (score 0):

Use [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Replace:

```
arsort($dev);
```

With

```
ksort($dev);
```

It will sort your array by the keys

If you need to reverse, use [array_reverse](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php):

```
ksort($dev);
$dev = array_reverse($dev);
```

Comment: Same output. It's more complicated than that ;-)

Comment: Thanks but as mentionned I need the values in desending order.

Comment: Edited, take a look. https://3v4l.org/HdumD But the result is equals to the result you expected in your question

Answer (score 0):

Custom defined sort function

```
uasort( $dev, function ( $a, $b ) {
    if ( intval( $a ) === intval( $b ) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return intval( $a ) > intval( $b ) ? -1 : +1;
} );
```